# Не работает клавиатура ноутбука при установке любого дистрибутива Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, manjaro

Пытался установить Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS как вторую ОС на ноутбук. Но при установке столкнулся с тем, что не могу ввести логин и пароль. Использовал Rufus. Пробовал и другие версии Ubuntu - тоже самое. Пробовал через экранную клавиатуру ввести команды в терминале, которые должны были помочь(так пишут в интернете), но в итоге и они не помогли. Потом попробовал установить Manjaro с помощью Ventoy. Безрезультатно. Однако на Virtual Box все работает. Что делать?

Ноутбук ASUS TUF Gaming A15 FA507NV-LP023

Comment: В интернете пишут так https://askubuntu.com/questions/1470529/asus-tuf-a15-2023-keyboard-not-working
т.е. помочь может либо самостоятельная сборка ядра, либо ждите обновлений

Comment: Помогла установка kernel 6.4.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помогла установка kernel 6.4.10